# Table State being On Hold?

Tags: usability, gui-design, tables

I'm trying to find a way to convey that a table row has been placed "on hold". Currently, I have an overlay that dims the row and states that it is "on hold" but cannot find any resources that show another way to display this kind of UI. Looking for alternative ways to show this that are beneficial to the user.

Comment: What does "on hold" mean?

Comment: @MattObee it's a state where a user can't interact because they may be waiting on something else, such as another document to be uploaded etc.

Comment: Dimming the background as you describe, as long as you have a text label as well, sounds like a reasonable solution. I guess the other important part of this is making it clear to the user _why_ it's on hold.

Comment: take a look to http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/67269/what-is-the-best-way-to-display-disabled-field-and-text-for-accessibility-color and http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45985/display-of-disabled-input-fields . Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but same as @MattObee says, as long as you explain **why**, you should be OK, just use a label or an icon if you have many instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking everyone's suggestions into account, here's a quick mockup of what I think this could look like:

[image: Locked Table Row with Explanations]